# links to external URL in a GWT app direct to the default place

Tags: java, angularjs, gwt

I have a GWT app in which I use an Angular directive (I put it in the main html file). Everything works fine until I press a link in the angular directive which should direct me to an external URL. Instead of opening the URL I see that the address bar changes accordingly but the page loaded is the default place I defined in the GWT app, meaning it doesn't leave the GWT, it only changes places. Can anyone shed some light ?

Comment: Could you give us the angular directive, the link you're expecting to reach, and the url you get ?